# Issue using REST API call in Angular JS code

Tags: json, angularjs, collections

The below function is working fine with Static data but when i get it using a REST API Call it is throwing error
 i an following the link http://angular-js.in/md-chips/

```
angular.module('mdChips', [])
.factory('chipsService', [function(){
    alert("chipservice");
    return {
        helper: function(scope, collection, active, rule, chipsList){
            if (active == -1 && collection.length > 0){
                collection[0].active = true;
            } else if (collection.length > 0){
                if (collection[active+rule]){
                    collection[active].active = false;
                    collection[active+rule].active = true;
                } else {
                    collection[active].active = false;
                    var index = rule == 1 ? 0 : (collection.length-1);
                    collection[index].active = true;
                }
            }
            scope.$apply();
            if (collection.length > 0)
                chipsList.querySelector('.active').scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"});
        },
        nextActive: function(scope, collection, active, chipsList){
            this.helper(scope, collection, active, 1, chipsList);
        },
        prevActive: function(scope, collection, active, chipsList){
            this.helper(scope, collection, active, -1, chipsList);
        }
    }
}])
.directive('mdChips', ['$compile','$timeout', '$document', 'chipsService', function($compile, $timeout, $document, chipsService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="md-chips" ng-cloak> \
                        <div class="chips-input-field"> \
                            <div class="input-chips-elements"> \
                                <div ng-repeat="chips in ngModel track by $index" class="chips-mini-item"> \
                                    <div class="chips-mini" ng-click="showMore($index, $event)"> \
                                         \
                                        <div class="chips-mini-title">{{chips[mdTitle]}}</div> \
                                    </div> \
                                </div> \
                                <div class="chips-active" ng-style="{top: ytop}" ng-model="ytop" ng-click="closeActive($event)"></div> \
                                <input type="text" ng-model="chipsText[mdTitle]" ng-focus="clearActive()" ng-keydown="clearPrev($event)" class="chipsInput"/> \
                            </div> \
                        </div> \
                    </div>',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
            collection: '=',
            ngModel: '=',
            text: '@',
            //mdItem: '@',
            mdTitle: '@',
            //mdThumbnail: '@',
            mdSubtitle: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.ytop = '10px';

            scope.innerCollection = scope.collection.map(function(item){
                if (!item[scope.mdTitle]){ 
                    alert(item[scope.mdTitle]);
                    return; 
                }

                if (!item[scope.mdSubtitle] && !item[scope.mdThumbnail]){
                    if (item[scope.mdItem].length < 1){
                        return;
                    } else {
                        item[scope.mdSubtitle] = item[scope.mdItem][0][scope.mdSubtitle];
                        item[scope.mdThumbnail] = item[scope.mdItem][0][scope.mdThumbnail] ? item[scope.mdItem][0][scope.mdThumbnail] : '';
                        item[scope.mdItem].shift();
                        return item;
                    }
                }
                item['active'] = false;
                return item;
            });

            element.bind('input', function(event) {
                console.log("event started");
                var self = scope;
                scope.clearActive();
                if (event.target.value) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        var list = angular.element("<div id='chips-list' ng-show='true' ng-cloak> \
                                                        <div ng-repeat='item in (filteredCollection = (innerCollection | filter:chipsText))' class='chips-list-item' ng-click=addToInput(item) ng-class='{active: item.active}'> \
                                                            <div class='chips-item-wrapper'> \
                                                                <div class='chips-image'> \
                                                                    <img ng-src='{{item[mdThumbnail]}}' ng-show='item[mdThumbnail] ? true : false'> \
                                                                    <div class='image-default' ng-show='item[mdThumbnail] ? false : true'></div> \
                                                                </div> \
                                                                <span class='chips-title'>{{item[mdTitle]}}</span> \
                                                                \
                                                            </div> \
                                                        </div> \
                                                    </div>");
                        $compile(list)(scope);  
                        $timeout(function() {
                            self.removeList();
                            element.append(list);
                        });

                    });
                } else {
                    self.removeList();
                }
            });


            $document.bind('click', function(evt){
                scope.clearActive();
                if(scope.chipsText){
                    scope.chipsText[scope.mdTitle] = '';
                }
                scope.removeList();
                scope.$apply();
            });

            element.bind('click', function(evt){
                evt.stopPropagation();
                element[0].querySelector('.chipsInput').focus();
            });

            scope.removeList = function(){
                this.innerCollection.forEach(function(item, index){
                        if(item.active){
                            item.active = false;
                        }
                });
                var chipsList = element[0].querySelector('#chips-list');
                if (chipsList) {
                    chipsList.parentNode.removeChild(chipsList);
                }
            };

            scope.addToInput = function(item){
                console.log("add to input");
                var chipsElement = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
                console.log(chipsElement);
                this.ngModel.push(chipsElement);
                this.chipsText[this.mdTitle] = '';
                this.removeList();
                element[0].querySelector('.chipsInput').focus();
            };

            scope.showMore = function(index, event){
                this.removeList();
                scope.ytop = event.currentTarget.offsetTop + 'px';
                var item = scope.ngModel[index],
                    chipsActive = element[0].querySelector('.chips-active');
                var show =  item[scope.mdThumbnail] ? true : false;
                var thumb = item[scope.mdThumbnail]? item[scope.mdThumbnail] : '';
                var htmlCode = '<div id ="chips-active-list" ng-cloak> \
                                    <div class="chips-active-main">  \
                                         \
                                        <div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" ng-click=deleteChips(' + index + ')><a></a></div> \
                                        <div class="chips-active-wrap"> \
                                            <div class="chips-active-title" >' + item[scope.mdTitle] + '</div> \
                                            \
                                        </div> \
                                    </div>';

                if (item[scope.mdItem] && item[scope.mdItem].length > 0){
                    for(var i=0; i < item[scope.mdItem].length; i++){
                        var url = item[scope.mdItem][i][scope.mdThumbnail] ? item[scope.mdItem][i][scope.mdThumbnail] : ''; 
                        show = url ? true : false;
                        htmlCode += '<div class="md-chips-single-line" ng-click=setOtherEmail(' + index + ',"'+url+'","' + item[scope.mdItem][i][scope.mdSubtitle] + '",' + i + ')>  \
                                <div class="chips-active-img"> \
                                    <img src="' + url + '" ng-show=' +  show + ' /> \
                                    <div class="chips-active-image-default" ng-show=' +  !show + '></div> \
                                </div> \
                                <div class="chips-active-wrap"> \
                                    <p class="chips-active-description-only">' + item[scope.mdItem][i][scope.mdSubtitle] + '</p> \
                                </div> \
                            </div>';
                    }
                }

                htmlCode += '</div>';
                var chips = angular.element(htmlCode);
                if (chipsActive.hasChildNodes()){
                    this.clearActiveChildren(chipsActive);
                }
                $compile(chips)(scope);
                $timeout(function() {
                    if (element[0].querySelector('#chips-list')){
                        this.chipsText[this.mdTitle] = ''; 
                        element[0].querySelector('#chips-list').remove();
                    }
                    chipsActive.appendChild(chips[0]);
                });


            };

            element.bind('keydown', function(kEv){
                var chipsList = element[0].querySelector('#chips-list');
                if (chipsList){
                    var active = -1;
                    scope.filteredCollection.forEach(function(item, index){
                        if(item.active){
                            active = index;
                        }
                    });
                    switch(kEv.keyCode){
                        case 40:
                            chipsService.nextActive(scope, scope.filteredCollection, active, chipsList);
                            break;  
                        case 38:
                            chipsService.prevActive(scope, scope.filteredCollection, active, chipsList);
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            if (active!==-1){
                                scope.addToInput(scope.filteredCollection[active]);
                                scope.removeList();
                                kEv.target.style.width = 20;
                                scope.$apply();
                            } else if (scope.chipsText[scope.mdTitle] ){
                                item = {};
                                item[scope.mdTitle] = scope.chipsText[scope.mdTitle]; 
                                item[scope.mdSubtitle] = scope.chipsText[scope.mdTitle];
                                scope.addToInput(item);
                                kEv.target.style.width = 20;
                                scope.$apply();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }); 

            scope.deleteChips = function(index){
                scope.ngModel.splice(index,1);
                this.clearActive();
            };

            scope.clearPrev = function(event){
                if(event.keyCode === 8 && event.target.value === '' && scope.ngModel.length !== 0){
                    scope.ngModel.pop();
                }
                if (scope.chipsText){
                    var length = scope.chipsText[scope.mdTitle].length * 15 + 15;
                    event.target.style.width = length ? length : 20;
                }
                return true;
            };

            scope.closeActive = function(event){
                if (event.currentTarget.hasChildNodes()){
                    this.clearActiveChildren(event.currentTarget);
                }
            };

            scope.clearActive = function(){
                var chipsActive = element[0].querySelector('.chips-active');
                this.clearActiveChildren(chipsActive);

            };

            scope.clearActiveChildren = function(active){
                while (active.firstChild) {
                    active.removeChild(active.firstChild);
                }
            };

            scope.setOtherEmail = function(index, url, email,i){
                var old = {};
                old.url = this.ngModel[index][scope.mdThumbnail];
                old.subtitle = this.ngModel[index][scope.mdSubtitle];
                if (url && url !== 'undefined'){    
                    this.ngModel[index][scope.mdThumbnail] = url;
                } else {
                    delete this.ngModel[index][scope.mdThumbnail];
                }
                this.ngModel[index][scope.mdSubtitle]  = email;
                this.ngModel[index][scope.mdItem][i][scope.mdSubtitle] = old.subtitle;
                this.ngModel[index][scope.mdItem][i][scope.mdThumbnail] = old.url;
            };


        }
    }

}]);
```

The error details are TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

HTML CODE

```
<md-chips collection='itemsCollection' ng-model='selectedUsers' text='To' md-title='Name'  md-subtitle='City'  class='input' />
```

Below is the ANgular JS Code . The collection is showing undefined value when i use the REST API Call

```
angular.module('mdChipsDemo', ['mdChips'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.itemsCollection = JSON.stringify(data.records);
        if ($scope.itemsCollection.length > 0) {
            alert(123);
            console.log($scope.itemsCollection);
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.errorMessage = "Couldn't load the list of customers, error # " + status;
    });
    $scope.selectedUsers = [];
    console.log($scope.selectedUsers);
});
```

Comment: What kind of collection is `scope.collection` and where do you define it? Are you sure it is already initialized? Rest calls run asyncronical. you have to move the assignment to scope.innerCollection to the succes callback function. A plunker/jsfiddle would help

Comment: hi ,thanks using http://angular-js.in/md-chips/             Michael

Answer (score 0):

This line: `$scope.itemsCollection = JSON.stringify(data.records);` sets the item as a `String` but then passes it into your directive.

The first action on the directive's `collection` is: `scope.innerCollection = scope.collection.map(...)`

```
typeof JSON.stringify(data.records).map; // => undefined
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2wtTphCfzJ5aHoErcfr?p=preview).